# Combining functional and OOP in tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, tkinter, functional-programming

I made an app using tkinter which basically take user input and upon clicking the appropriate button, it will run a function to process them and return an output.

The program works as intended, however I am confused on how appropriate it is to combine functional and OOP style of program building.

My app consists of two python file. The first file, lets call it GUI.py, looks like this:

```
from secondfile import *
class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master 
    .................
    
    def proceed():
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Window2(self.newWindow, self)

class Window2:
    ........ 
    thisThread = threading.Thread(
                      target =simple_func_but_expensive, 
                      args   = (....))

    def run_the_prog2():
        thr.start()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry(....)
    root.title(.....)
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The second file (secondfile.py) consists of:

```
def supporting_function_1(....):
    .........
def supporting_function_2(....):
    .........
def supporting_function_...(....):
    .........
def supporting_function_20(....):
    .........
def simple_func_but_expensive(.......):
    .........
```

I was thinking of restructuring the second file with class, but each function in secondfile.py don't really share instance variable that much. Also, the program is able to run another instance of simple_func_but_expensive() because of root.mainloop() so I don't think OOP is necessary in the function file.

However, it seems that most programs use OOP and I see it as more computer science appropriate. Any opinion on this?

Comment: " I see it as more computer science appropriate" It isn't. Are you actually talking about functional programming, though? That doesn't mean just having module-level functions, rather, it's also about using pure-functions that avoid side-effects and mutate state. Note, OOP and Functional programing are actually not mutually exclusive. Although OOP languages are often imperative, scala is an example of a popular language that is a class-based, OOP language that is neverthless a functional programming language

Comment: In any case, what you are doing here is perfectly fine. Not everything has to be a class definition, this is Python, not Java. But fundamentally, this question is too opinion-based...